# Update all child in Firebase

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In a database from Firebase, I need to update the value open and pass it to false for all child. How I can do it in Javascript ?
Something like this

```
let dbCon = firebase.database().ref("/messages/" + *);
    dbCon.update({
      open: false
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Update your state through a for loop or so? Your state should be synced to Firebase?

Comment: I edit it to explain, yes it have to be synced to firebase

Comment: Check out https://github.com/tylermcginnis/re-base

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Firebase Database has no equivalent to SQL's `UPDATE messages SET open=false`.

To update a node in Firebase, you must first have a reference to that specific node. And to get a reference to a node, you must know the full path to that node.

This means that you'll first need to read the data, then loop over it, and then update each child in turn. In code:

```
let dbCon = firebase.database().ref("/messages/");
dbCon.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
    child.ref.update({
      open: false
    });
  });
});
```