# Update item in each node of a collection in a Realtime Database using Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

We've got a collection of profiles in a Firebase Realtime Database that we'd like to update. The structure is simple

**/profiles**

- abc `{ key1: value, key2: value }`
- deg `{ key1: value, key2: value }`
- xyz `{ key1: value, key2: value }`

Each item is an object with some key/value pairs and we'd like to add a new key/value pair to **all** items in the collection (approx 5000 of them) so that:

- abc `{ key1: value, key2: value, key3: value }`
- deg `{ key1: value, key2: value, key3: value }`
- xyz `{ key1: value, key2: value, key3: value }`

Is there a way to do this using the Firebase CLI database:push or database:set methods?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to update an item in the database, you must know the full path to that item. So to update all child nodes of a location, you'll need to:

1. read the data at that location
2. iterate over the child nodes
3. update each child node

There is no built-in single operation for this in the Firebase CLI, although you can compose it by combining the `datbase:get` and `database:update` [commands](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#database_commands), with a custom script that iterates over the child nodes.

I personally prefer to do these in regular code though, since it's quite easy to write such an update loop in JavaScript (so that it can run in a browser, or on Node.js). See for an example, my answer here: [Update all child in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49719026).

Comment: So no magic way to do it using the CLI - we'll have to go down the NodeJS path. Okay thanks Frank.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way. Using `update`.

Pseudo-code

```
let data = {};
// push key3 data 
for loop profile_name {
   data[`profiles/${profile_name}/key3`] = key3_value;
}
ref.update(data);
```

I'm not sure about the limit. You can read more here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data

Comment: Hi @tuledev - we're looking to do it using the CLI, that looks like NodeJS code.